# Axibase Time Series Database - filter out negative values on time chart

Tags: graph, charts, time-series, axibase

I am using [Axibase Time Series Database](http://axibase.com/products/axibase-time-series-database/) Community Edition, version 10552, to store my photovoltaic and sun altitude data. Sun altitude values are negative during the night time and I don't want to see them on my graphs.

How can I view only the positive values? Anyone know a setting or a trick that can acheive this?

Here is my current [Time Chart widget](http://axibase.com/products/axibase-time-series-database/visualization/widgets/time-chart/) configuration:

```
[widget]
  type = chart
  title = PV power
  timespan = 3 day
  entity = pvout.25630

[series]
  label = Sun Altitude at (-35.3089, 149.2004)
  metric = sun_altitude
  color = orange
   [tags]
    lat = -35.3089 
    lon = 149.2004
```

Here is a screenshot of what I am actually seeing at the moment:

[image]

Here is an example in Chart Lab:

https://axibase.com/chartlab/3170e35d/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question.

There are several ways to hide or filter out the negative values:

1. [replace-value](http://axibase.com/products/axibase-time-series-database/visualization/widgets/configuring-the-widgets/) setting uses an expression to modify or filter series values:

   ```
   [widget]
     type = chart
     title = PV power
     timespan = 3 day
     entity = pvout.25630

   [series]
     label = Sun Altitude at (-35.3089, 149.2004)
     metric = sun_altitude
     color = orange

     replace-value = value < 0 ? null : value

     [tags]
      lat=-35.3089 
      lon=149.2004
   ```

This expression will filter out all values that are less than 0 from the series.

Results: https://axibase.com/chartlab/3170e35d/3/

[image: replace-value]

2. [min-range-force](http://axibase.com/products/axibase-time-series-database/visualization/widgets/configuring-the-widgets/) setting can be used to set the minimum range of the y-axis:

   ```
   [widget]
     type = chart
     title = PV power
     timespan = 3 day
     entity = pvout.25630

     min-range-force = 0

   [series]
     label = Sun Altitude at (-35.3089, 149.2004)
     metric = sun_altitude
     color = orange

     [tags]
      lat=-35.3089 
      lon=149.2004
   ```

Results: https://axibase.com/chartlab/3170e35d/4/

[image]

3. If you are using a script to calculate the Sun Altitude, then you can use the `Math.max` function:

   ```
   [widget]
     type = chart
     title = PV power
     timespan = 3 day

   [series]
     label = Altitude
     #API: SunCalc.getPosition = function (date, lat, lng)
     value = var pos = SunCalc.getPosition(new Date(time), -35.3089, 149.2004);
     value = return Math.max(0, pos.altitude)
     frequency = 30 minute
     color = orange
   ```

Results: https://axibase.com/chartlab/3170e35d/5/

[image]

4. [value equation](http://axibase.com/products/axibase-time-series-database/visualization/widgets/configuring-the-widgets/) can be used to create a computed series, excluding the negative values:

   ```
   [widget]
     type = chart
     title = PV power
     timespan = 3 day
     entity = pvout.25630

   [series]
     metric = sun_altitude
     display = false
     alias = sun_alt

    [tags]
     lat=-35.3089 
     lon=149.2004

   [series]
     label = Sun Altitude at (-35.3089, 149.2004)
     value = Math.max(0, value('sun_alt'))
     color = orange
   ```

In this case, we hide the original series and assign an alias, then we use the `value = Math.max(0, value('sun_alt'))` equation to create a new computed series without the negative values.

Results: https://axibase.com/chartlab/3170e35d/6/

[image]